# How to remove the panel's menu-bar, and decorations for all local windows under Gnome?

Tags: gnome, gconf, menu-bar, window-decoration

I'm running Gnome version 3.4.1 and the script in charge of disabling menu-bar and decorations will run locally (no sudoing). It might have to do with `gconftool-2`, `gsettings` or `compiz` (all available in this Ubuntu-12.04-based distro), but I can't figure out how. Out of that, this old release is plenty of configuration (`xml`) files, but again, after much searching don't know where to touch.

Note: Everything should be done with core commands and in the home directories, as the user cannot install software, nor alter system's files.